# How can a generate an expression like a0 + a1 e1 + a2 e2 +a3 e3 + a4 e1 e2 + a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3?

Tags: list-manipulation, expression-construction

I wish to input `n` and then generate an expression. It would look like the above when $n = 3$. I would like to use subscripts for `a0`, `a1`, ... and `e1`, `e2`, and `e3`. The subscripts of `a` simply increment by one each time.

Comment: so `a` just increases, and `e` goes up to `3` after which you add another `e`? Why is `e3` followed by `e1 e2`? Also, how is this an array?

Comment: What you show is NOT an "array."  This question is extremely unclear and hence insoluble because the desired pattern of terms is not defined.  Also it is unclear whether you DO or DO NOT want subscripting!  And "both."  "Both" what?  How about `myeq[n_] := Total@Table[Subscript[a, i], {i, n}]; myeq[5]`

Comment: maybe `Subsets[Range[n]]` is useful

Comment: Sorry. After this was edited, it did not print out as I had intended. I had difficulty copying my attempts here. Let me simplify.

Comment: Sorry. My inputs to the editor must have gotten garbled. Let me simplify based upon the comments I see. I wish to input n and generate an expression. When n = 3 the expression should look like a0 + a1 e1 +a2 e2 + a3 e3 + a4 e1 e2 + a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3. Yes, the subscripts of a simply increment each time. Yes, I would prefer subscripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Rewritten to give the correct output and do it more cleanly using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot.html):*

```
f3[n_] :=
  Array[Subscript[a, #] &, 2^n - 1].
    Subsets[Product[Subscript[e, i], {i, n}], n - 1]
```

Which looks like this when formatted by the Front End (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>):

[image]

- Note: a quick way to convert a list (vector) to a sum is to use [`Tr`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tr.html), e.g. `Tr[{a, b, c}]`

Comment: Thank you, all. All 3 answers are wonderful and all provide different answers (even #1 and #2 are slightly different if you look closely; #1 is the one I prefer of the two). I have decided that subscripts are preferred since I have AT LAST discovered “InputForm” and so I can how convert subscripted expressions to strings for further manipulation (ToString [x, InputForm] ). I prefer the subscript form but as a summation rather than a list. I am attempting to learn to do this and will respond further in a day or two whether or not I have succeeded. You have given me a lot to learn here.

Comment: @matrixbud Leaving the output as a list was simply a mistake.  I'll correct it.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Wizard. I figured out one way to convert your answer into a summation.    Plus @@ Subsets[f2[3], {1}] works, for example, for n=3. I suspect using Subsets is overkill but I am still just learning this stuff. It would be cleaner if I could modify the definition of f[2] rather than applying the change after-the-fact.

Comment: @matrixbud `Plus @@ f2[3]` or as noted in the answer `Tr[ f2[3] ]` should give the output you want, and both could be included in the definition.  But `f3` is cleaner, no?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way:

```
f[n_] := Total[
  MapIndexed[#1 ToExpression["a" <> IntegerString[#2[[1]] - 1]] &, 
   Subsets[Array[ToExpression["e" <> IntegerString[#]] &, n, 1, 
     Times], {0, n - 1}]]]
```

Testing outputs:

```
f[3]

(* a0 + a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a4 e1 e2 + a3 e3 + a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3 *)

f[4]

(* a0 + a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a5 e1 e2 + a3 e3 + a6 e1 e3 + a8 e2 e3 + 
  a11 e1 e2 e3 + a4 e4 + a7 e1 e4 + a9 e2 e4 + a12 e1 e2 e4 + 
  a10 e3 e4 + a13 e1 e3 e4 + a14 e2 e3 e4 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

From your last comment here's a crude way to get the expression

```
a0 + a1 e1 + a2 e2 + a3 e3 + a4 e1 e2 + a5 e1 e3 + a6 e2 e3
```

with `n = 3` from a function:

```
f[n_] := Module[{a, e, t, terms, i, j},
  e = Table[ToExpression["e" <> ToString[i]], {i, n}];
  terms = {1};
  Do[t = Table[1, {j, i}]; 
   terms = Flatten[{terms, 
      Apply[List, Expand[AugmentedSymmetricPolynomial[t, e]/i!]]}],
   {i, n - 1}];
  Table[ToExpression["a" <> ToString[i]], {i, 0, Length[terms] - 1}].terms]

f[2]
(* a0+a1 e1+a2 e2 *)
f[3]
(* a0+a1 e1+a2 e2+a4 e1 e2+a3 e3+a5 e1 e3+a6 e2 e3 *)
f[4]
(* a0+a1 e1+a2 e2+a5 e1 e2+a3 e3+a6 e1 e3+a7 e2 e3+a11 e1 e2 e3+a4 
e4+a8 e1 e4+a9 e2 e4+a12 e1 e2 e4+a10 e3 e4+a13 e1 e3 e4+a14 e2 e3 e4 *)
```

But I think you need to edit your question to give a few more specifics.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all 3 of you. 3 good answers. I ultimately used something very close to Mr. Wizard's answer because it is the easiest to understand. I learned about Modules from Jim Baldwin for which I thank him. JHM's solution is also very short and I could easily have used a version of it as I show below.

[image]